# Pandas merge leads to scientific number

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am reading my data like this

```
left = pd.read_csv('Day1.csv', sep='\t')
right = pd.read_csv('Day2.csv', sep='\t')
```

and my data looks like this

```
76561193665298435   28  33210   1.0     85
76561193665298436   29  33340   56.0    56
76561193665298437   30  8930    800.0   2717
```

Imagine I have two dataframes almost the same and I want to merge them. If I use:

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, how='left', on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

the output is perfect no problem just like the original dataframes. But I need keys from both the dataframes so I use:

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

and there starts the problem and my data looks like this:

```
7.65611936653e+16   33210.0     1.0     85.0    1.0     85.0
7.65611936653e+16   33340.0     56.0    56.0    56.0    56.0
7.65611936653e+16   8930.0      800.0   2717.0  800.0   2717.0
7.65611936653e+16   221680.0    49.0    803.0   49.0    803.0
```

I need to get rid of this scientific form because I can't do any more processing (all the keys look the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i have been looking for this for a while but i just found the answer, so if anyone has the same problem here is the solution. You need to convert it to string and here is how:

```
left['key1'] = left['key1'].astype('str')
```

Comment: i tried it and it didnt, dont know why. I am using python 2.7